# Background Image Sticking Out Below Sticky Footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, sticky-footer

I've just added a background image to a div on my homepage which sits in between my header and footer, and it is causing my sticky footer to sit at the bottom of the window instead of below the background image - so the background image sticks out below the footer... How can I get my sticky footer to sit below the div with the background image?

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <header style="position: static;">
     <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="search" style="float: left; width: 20%; position: absolute; left: 0;">
     <input type="text" class="st-default-search-input" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #EEE1DC; color: #000; font-weight: 400; float: left;">
     </div>
     <div class="social" style="right: 0; position: absolute;">
        <a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/insta-ico.png" /></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/fb-ico.png" /></a>
        <a href="mailto:info@summerheart.co.za"><img src="images/email-ico.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div data-embed_type="cart" data-shop="summerheart.myshopify.com" data-checkout_button_text="Checkout" data-cart_button_text="" data-button_text_color="000" data-button_background_color="FAEDE8" data-background_color="transparent" data-text_color="757575" data-accent_color="FAEDE8" data-cart_title="Your cart" style="float: right; right: 0; margin-right: 20px; padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999;"></div>
        <div class="logo"><a href="home.html"><img src="images/sh_logo3.png" /></a></div>
        <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
           <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
           <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="home.html" aria-haspopup="true">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="shop.html" aria-haspopup="true">SHOP</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html" aria-haspopup="true">ABOUT</a>
              <li><a href="sizing.html">SIZING</a></li>
              <li><a href="video.html">VIDEO</a></li>
              <li><a href="press.html">PRESS</a></li>
              <li><a href="social.html">SOCIAL</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
     </div>
  </header>
  <div id="hero"></div>
  <!--<div style="background-color: #FAEDE8; z-index: 0; position: inherit;">
     <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: 400; color: #000; letter-spacing: 1px; padding: 2px;">FREE SHIPPPING ON ALL ORDERS</p>
  </div>-->
  <footer>
     <div class="foot-wrap">
        <div class="foot-list-left">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="privacy.html">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
              <li><a href="terms.html">TERMS OF USE</a></li>
              <li><a href="customer.html">CUSTOMER SERVICE</a></li>
              <li><a href="orders.html">ORDERS</a></li>
              <li><a href="returns.html">RETURN POLICY</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="foot-list-right">
           <ul>
              <li>© 2015 SUMMERHEART</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #FAEDE8;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
margin: 0 0 50px;
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #FAEDE8;
color: #000;
overflow: hidden;
}

#hero { 
position: absolute;  
min-height: 100%; 
background-size: cover;  
width: 100%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-o-user-select: none; 
user-select: none;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And lastly the JavaScript

```
$(function() {
      var images = ['hero1.jpg', 'hero2.jpg', 'hero3.jpg', 'hero4.jpg', 'hero5.jpg', 'hero6.jpg', 'hero7.jpg', 'hero8.jpg', 'hero9.jpg'];
      $('#hero').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
     });
```

Any thoughts as to what is causing the jump?

here is the page in question - http://japesfawcett.com/testsh/hometest.html

Comment: You might not get a real answer because you didn't post the real code. The culprit seems to be your absolute  positioning and possibly the `min-height` of your `#hero`.

Comment: Mocked it up in JS Fiddle with this code and don't see anything wrong. Do you have a link to the site in question?

Comment: I've added the full html, and linked to the page so you guys can see! Removing the min-height is causing the background image to disappear, as you can see at the link I've added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code, (and as MinusFour) pointed out. You're issue is the `min-width:100%` on your `#hero` div.

Remove this and you will be back in business!

Min-height 100% means that the smallest that div could ever be is, well, 100% of the window. This was causing your footer to sit at the `bottom` of your window instead of the page.

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcn9vpzd/2/)** showing you the change.

---

Solution 2:

Alright, try this out:

Here is your new **HTML structure**. I kept all of your original class names so you shouldn't have to rename everything...

```
        <div data-embed_type="cart" data-shop="summerheart.myshopify.com" data-checkout_button_text="Checkout" data-cart_button_text="" data-button_text_color="000" data-button_background_color="FAEDE8" data-background_color="transparent" data-text_color="757575" data-accent_color="FAEDE8" data-cart_title="Your cart" style="float: right; right: 0; margin-right: 20px; padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999;"></div>
        <div class="logo"><a href="home.html"><img src="images/sh_logo3.png" /></a></div>
        <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
          <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
          <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html" aria-haspopup="true">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html" aria-haspopup="true">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" aria-haspopup="true">ABOUT</a>
            <li><a href="sizing.html">SIZING</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html">VIDEO</a></li>
            <li><a href="press.html">PRESS</a></li>
            <li><a href="social.html">SOCIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>



    <div id="content">
      <div id="hero"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="foot-wrap">
      <div class="foot-list-left">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="privacy.html">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms.html">TERMS OF USE</a></li>
          <li><a href="customer.html">CUSTOMER SERVICE</a></li>
          <li><a href="orders.html">ORDERS</a></li>
          <li><a href="returns.html">RETURN POLICY</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="foot-list-right">
        <ul>
          <li>© 2015 SUMMERHEART</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Here is the main part I added to your **CSS**, but I did create the JSFiddle with your *entire* `main.css` file, so it *should* just be a copy/paste solution. Apologies for the CSS being a little messy in the fiddle.

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.site-wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

#content{
      position: absolute;
    z-index: -94;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.footer, .push {
height: 4em;
z-index:12;
position:absolute;
}

.footer, .push {
clear: both;
}
```

Here is the **[Full Screen JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y983dvgn/17/embedded/result/)**

Here is the **[Code View JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y983dvgn/17/)**

Hopefully this solves your problem! Let me know!

*You may need to mess with some `z-index` on your header, but that's a small change.

Comment: I suspected that might be the culprit, however removing that is causing my background image to disappear... here is a link to the page in question with that change made [link](http://japesfawcett.com/testsh/hometest.html)

Comment: Is the hero container being rendered in dynamically?

Comment: Hmm... would you be open to restructuring your HTML slightly?

Comment: Yeah for sure, if it helps sort out this issue!

Comment: Got it! updating answer now

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort, really appreciate it! This really helped! Managed to get it exactly how I wanted after a few tweaks! [Link](http://japesfawcett.com/testsh/home.html)

Comment: Good stuff, yeah, as soon as I posted the answer I realized the image was taking the whole window but I had to get back to work so I couldn't correct it. Glad you were able to get it all together!